# Jquery how to select all first paragraphs in all div element

Tags: jquery

Say there is

```
<html>
    <div>
         <p>1. para in 1. div</p>
         <p>2. para in 1. div</p>
    </div>
    <div>
         <p>1. para in 2. div</p>
         <p>2. para in 2. div</p>
    </div>
</html>
```

How would I - using Jquery - select every first paragraph in all divs? So there would be `<p>1 para in 1. div</p>` and `<p>1. para in 2. div</p>` both selected.

So far tried `$(div p:first)` and similars with no luck.

Comment: use : first selector

Comment: I've tried it, It causes selecting only '1.para in 1.div',

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `:first-child`.

> Selects all elements that are the first child of their parent.

```
$('div  p:first-child')
```

Comment: @pzeszko: glad it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/k40nrLhj/)

```
$("#qwe").click(function () {
    var a = $('#parentdiv').find('p:nth-child(1)');
    a.each(function () {
        alert($(this).html());
    });
});
```

Comment: Nice solution, after all I think in most cases people should use  something similar: p-nth-of-type(1), but in my particular sitiuation your answer is ofc correct.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery's **[:first Selector](https://api.jquery.com/first-selector/)**

`$('div p:first-child')`

Comment: Actually your second idea was my first thought, and it does not work.

Comment: oops your correct didn't see it was for all elements:)

Answer (score 0):

All `<p>` elements that are the first child of their parent

```
$("div p:first-child")
```